# Unable to kill application from Yarn RM UI

Tags: hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc, livy

I have dataproc setup on google cloud platform with apache livy installed.
I am submitting jobs using livy rest api.
When I try to kill livy jobs from Yarn RM, I am getting below error in browser console tab.

```
{"RemoteException":{"exception":"AuthorizationException","message":"Unable to obtain user name, user not authenticated","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException"}}
```

When I open Yarn RM.
I am not sure how to setup user authentication for Yarn RM Web interface.
Also when I open yarn ui, it does not ask me any username and password.

However I am able to kill application using below command

```
yarn application -kill application_id
```

Comment: How did you configure auth in Livy? When I try to repro with default settings other than setting `livy.spark.master` and `livy.spark.deploy-mode` after using the [init action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/livy/livy.sh), I'm able to kill the Livy jobs from the YARN RM GUI without any issue.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?  I tried Karthik Palaniappan's answer below but it did not work for me, though I'm not using Dataproc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699586/cant-kill-yarn-apps-using-resourcemanager-ui-after-hdp-3-1-0-0-78-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dataproc-discuss/WXjbXhVwB3w), this is a regression in Dataproc 1.3, assuming you are using that image version.

You would also hit this issue if you used the Tez init action on older Dataproc versions, since it also installs and configures the app timeline server.

You just need to set `hadoop.http.filter.initializers=org.apache.hadoop.security.HttpCrossOriginFilterInitializer,org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter`.

I plan to fix this in Dataproc 1.3 (will roll out in the next couple weeks), and I filed an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/371) for the Tez init action.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I'm not using Dataproc, could you shine more light on what the root cause could be?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699586/cant-kill-yarn-apps-using-resourcemanager-ui-after-hdp-3-1-0-0-78-upgrade

Comment: There's more context in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dataproc-discuss/WXjbXhVwB3w, which might help you dig into the YARN code. Looks like you set the filters correctly, so not sure what else might cause your issue.